# Complicated Table Merging

Tags: mysql

So being the complete SQL moron I am I need some kind help if possible.

Say I have two tables organized as follows:

```
map | authid | name | time | date | ... (other fields)
```

I am trying to merge the two into one. I wish to replace a row iff the authid and map values are the same. When a row needs to be merged, the values in all other fields should be retrieved from the table in which the time value is the lowest (and the old field values don't need to be kept of course since they're being replaced). All other rows from the other table in which there is a different map or authid value should be appended.

I am also needing to merge two other tables somewhat similarly:

```
pid | type | distance | ... (other fields)
```

The row needs to be replaced iff the pid value and the type value are the same. The table values that should be kept are those where the distance value is the greatest. New rows should be appended from the other table if the pid or type values are different.

Comment: Nice job explaining your requirements. All that's missing is an attempt to do something to write SQL to fulfill them. What have you tried so far that isn't working for you?

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: If I knew where to begin I would have posted that. I just don't see how something this complicated is possible purely through SQL (ie. with no help from PHP). I guess I will just scrap the data from my less populated databases and share the largest database amongst all my servers.

Comment: A quick search of the MySQL documentation turns up [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html), which may do what you want. "REPLACE is a MySQL extension to the SQL standard. It either inserts, or deletes and inserts." Did you think to actually check the documentation? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly quickly thrown together, will need continued work, was NOT tested at all, replace `...` with the remaining column names, change the `CREATE TABLE` lines to include types. May also need more explicit column references depending on your database's settings.

```
CREATE TABLE t12 (map, authid, name, time, date, ...);

INSERT VALUES INTO t12 (
    SELECT map, authid, name, time, date, ...
    FROM (
        SELECT map, authid, name, time, date, ...
        FROM (
            SELECT map, authid, name, time, date, ... FROM t1
            UNION 
            SELECT map, authid, name, time, date, ... FROM t2
        ) AS tc
        ORDER BY time DESC
    ) AS ts
    GROUP BY map, authid
);

CREATE TABLE t34 (pid, type, distance, ...);

INSERT VALUES INTO t34 (
    SELECT pid, type, distance, ...
    FROM (
        SELECT pid, type, distance, ...
        FROM (
            SELECT pid, type, distance, ... FROM t3
            UNION
            SELECT pid, type, distance, ... FROM t4
        ) AS tc
        ORDER BY time DESC
    ) AS ts
    GROUP BY pid, type
);
```